# Why is current flowing through the transistor though the base is off?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

What could be wrong in this circuit?

I'm new so I'm still figuring it out. I assume it's because I don't have a resistor placed at the emitter. I did that on purpose because I'm just testing it out.

Why do you think current passes through this transistor though you can clearly see that the base is off?

[image] [image]

Comment: Sorry, but nobody here knows surely how healthy the transistor is, is it really a transistor and what's its pinout. Maybe you can give the type of the transistor, the symbolic schematic of the attempted circuit and what there's exactly  at the other ends of the wires out of your photo. Otherwise your question is closed soon.

Comment: If it's a MOSFET and u leave the gate floating (no connection) it can easily pass current.   Pin #2 has no connection that I can see

Comment: Hi so i added the schematics

Comment: It's not a mosfet tho, and pin2 actually has a connection, regardless if it has or not it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited your question and corrected all of the spellings. Please don't use texting abbreviations in your posts - spell words in full. Such shorthand it may be unfamiliar to community members from around the globe and it doesn't engage readers in general. Typing in full is pretty-much just as quick and easy. Thanks.

Comment: Pin2 is the collector of a 2SC1815, not the base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the base is connected.

The [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/pdfjsview/web/viewer.html?file=//pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/30083/TOSHIBA/2SC1815/+2018WUPLRhpDDdtXpNGv.+/datasheet.pdf) for the 2SC1815 lists its pinout as ECB, so you've connected the LED in series with the base-emitter junction; your schematic is incorrect.

This is what you've actually made:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLrvs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You're lucky you didn't kill the transistor and the LED by doing this; your power supply either has a really high output impedance, or exactly the right voltage.

Comment: OHHHH MYYY GOOODNESSS THANK UUU  I never new there were transistors that used ECB

Comment: Every possible pin configuration is used by something, somewhere. Always read the datasheet.

Comment: For little TO92, Oriental transistor pins are ECB, European transistor pins are CBE, American transistor pins are EBC.